# Как из списка выразить x1,y,1,x2,y2

Tags: python, python-3.x

У меня есть задача в котором нужно найти периметр четырехугольника,зная только координаты точек. На ввод у меня есть`"#LB1:1#RB4:1#LT1:3#RT4:3"`. Я использую регулярку и забераю числа.

Что бы обчислить периметр четырехугольника, для начала мне нужно найти `dist`. Как из списка `a`, мне выразить `х1,y1,x2,y2`

```
dist = sqrt((x2 - x1) ** 2 + (y2 - y1) ** 2)
```

Мой код:

```
def perimetr(data):
    a = []
    result = re.findall(r'\d',data)
    for i in result:
        a.append(i)
    #dist = sqrt((x2 - x1) ** 2 + (y2 - y1) ** 2)
    return a
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Показанная формула считает ни разу не периметр, а длину диагонали...

Comment: Ваша регулярка будет правильно работать только для чисел из одной цифры

Answer (score 0):

```
a = ['1', '1', '4', '1', '1', '3', '4', '5']

x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, x4, y4 = [int(i) for i in a]
```

или просто `x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, x4, y4 = a` если до этого выше в функции писать `a.append(int(i))`